# Cassandra error during read - NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662481/cassandra-query-failures-all-hosts-tried-for-query-failed-no-host-was-tried) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770889/nohostavailableexception-all-hosts-tried-for-query-failed-no-host-was-tried), but couldn't find any solution.

I'm getting 'no host was tried' error only during read query. Writing to cassandra works fine. I'm using datastax cassandra java driver - 3.3.0.

I am trying the following read query as 'health-check':

```
SELECT * from counter_table;
```

Some code snippet which creates the Cluster:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPointsWithPorts(convertToInternetAddress())
    .withAuthProvider(authProvider)
    .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
    .withRetryPolicy(cassandraRetryPolicy)
    .build();
```

Edit 1: I've updated the sample query which gives this error for the 1st time. I'm querying a table with counter fields without giving any partition key. However, there are only 5 records in the table

Edit 2: Decreasing the cluster pool timeout seems to have fixed it. Any idea why?

Comment: can you share some example code where this error occures?

Comment: @Mandraenke it was a working code, and the read stopped working. I've added one of the queries that is failing.

Comment: @Mandraenke I've added a couple of edits with more info

Comment: "However, there are only 5 records in the table" - Right, but they could be stored on 5 different nodes.  Even small payloads with unbound queries can be bad.

Comment: @Aaron why would decreasing the cluster pool timeout fix it? I changed it to 5000 millis to 10000 millis, and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. I was using multiple sessions, and one of the sessions was getting closed.
The queries using the closed session were giving this error.